# Last Activity in Project in Jira 3.13.5

Tags: android-activity, jira

I've 847 Projects in Jira **3.13.5**. Now i want to clean it. I want to backup and delete all Projects, which haven't any activity in 2012. But how can I check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JIRA SOAP API:
Get all your project keys using *getProjectsNoSchemes* method.
To find out the most recently updated issue from each project, iterate over all of those keys and run:

```
jiraSoapService.getIssuesFromJqlSearch(authToken, "project = " + projectKey + " ORDER BY updatedDate", 1);
```

Note the **1** as the last argument - this limits the JQL result to only 1 issue, since we order the query by updatedDate this gives us the single, most recently updated issue from given project.

Just check if updatedDate of that issue is below 2012-01-01 and you've got your answer.

Here's javadoc for JIRA SOAP API: http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/latest/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html

Here's a tutorial on how to create a JIRA SOAP client: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Creating+a+JIRA+SOAP+Client#CreatingaJIRASOAPClient-Step2.CreatetheSOAPclientproject

**EDIT:** Sorry, just realized that JIRA 3.13 doesn't have JQL searches yet so  the answer is not valid for this JIRA version.

Comment: No Problem! And thank you! It help me a lot with a newer version!